# how to fetch data from sybase and load into MS-SQL with java

Tags: java

how to fetch data from sybase and load into MS-SQL with java?

Our client have data in Sybase database now I want to take that data and transfer to mssql dataBase with java. Can any body please help me?

Thanks

Comment: is using an etl tool not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're all set on doing this in Java, it should be easy enough to get JDBC drivers for each Sybase and MsSQL and write the translation logic yourself.  That is to say, table by table you are going to need to do...
1.  Using JDBC SELECT * FROM table.  This will produce a ResultSet.
2.  for each member of the ResultSet you will need to do a corresponding INSERT into the MS-SQL database

The trick is going to be that the schema will already need to be set on the MS-SQL side as I know of no way to infer DDL across the JDBC connection.  You will also have sequencing issues for any Foreign Key constraints that are in place.  Autogenerated values is also going to be a pain-in-the-butt.

There has got to be a way to do this with raw SQL way to do this.

Comment: Thank you Bob, Thanks for your answer First I try with this and I update you.